# How to express this integral in terms of known functions

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I need to find a primitive of

$$\sqrt{4 - \cos^2\!x \over 1 + 4\,\cos x}$$

or alternatively of

$$\sqrt{4 - v^2 \over (1 + 4 v)(1 - v^2)}.$$

Not in terms of elementary functions. Even special functions would be fine.
Or at least the definite integral for $x$ from 0 to $\arccos(-1/4)$ (for $v$ from -1/4 to 1).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the integral for $x$ from $\arccos(-1/4)$ to $\frac \pi 2$? or to $\frac {3\pi}2$? I ask since $\cos 1$ is not $0$. Also note that $\arccos(-1/4)$ will be between $\frac \pi 2$ and $\pi$. So in either case of $1$ or $\pi/2$ as the upper limit, you would be integrating in the reverse direction.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I meant from 0 to $\arccos(-1/4)$, where the denominator vanishes.

Comment: In that case, you also need $v$ from $-1/4$ to $1$, since $\cos 0 = 1$. You should edit your question (see the link on the lower left) to make these corrections.